# Function argument: original variable is modified even if passed by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a function which basically uses the dijkstra's algorithm to find distances in a graph

```
def getDistances(q,start):

print(q)

q[start][0] = 0
queue = [start]
while len(queue):


    m = []


    mMin = queue[0]
    m = q[mMin][2]
    queue.remove(mMin)


    for x in q[m][3]:

        if q[x][1] == 0:

            if not x in queue:
                queue.append(x)

            if q[x][0] > q[m][0] + 1:

                q[x][0] = q[m][0] + 1

    q[m][1] = 1

return [x[0] for x in q]
```

But it works perfectly. However, I have to call this function several times. and the "q" argument stays the same. Here's the invocation:

```
for ex in exits:
    dist = getDistances(list(qt),ex)
    distances.append([ex,dist])
```

"qt" itself is a list which contains a lot of different parameters. In this case I consider it not as important as the problem itself.

**The problem**
"qt" variable is modified if the "q" variable is modified inside the function. As you can see in invocation, i have tried to use `list(qt)` to pass the variable by value not by reference. 
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy

dist = getDistances(deepcopy(qt), ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the elements in the list too. As for example: `q[x][0] = q[m][0] + 1` modifies them. Do:

```
dist = getDistances(list(list(e) for e in qt), ex)
```